# Google play store not working

Tags: google-play-store

I have rooted my LYK-4503 from kingroot and then I uninstall the app and now I am not able to open google play store and I am not able to download or update any app... Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Restoring the Stock rom, Just download the Latest version of the Play Store from the web and then move it to the System/app folder. Also, I recommend you don't use KingRoot. Instead, get a custom recovery and Flash SuperSu.

Answer (score 0):

Kingroot really is a pain to work with. Only use it if nothing else works.

To fix your problem you should find the suitable version of gapps at [opengapps.org](http://opengapps.org). Make sure to select the correct architecture and android version and use a Gapps package `micro` or higher.

Once you download the zip, copy it to your phone and install it with a recovery.